# warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion

Tags: c, char, c-strings

I am attempting to change the last character in a word to make it the plural version of that word. For example bus to buses or penny to pennies. I get a warning when I try to set the last character equal to the plural ending. Please let me know what I need to change in order to fix this problem. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
  
  char word[50];
  char *last_char;


  printf("Enter a word: "); 
  scanf("%[^\t\n]", word);
  last_char = &word[(strlen(word)-1)];
  

  if(*last_char == 'y')
  {
    *last_char = "ies";
    printf("\nthis does not work %s", word);
  }

  else if(*last_char == 's')
  {
    *last_char = "es";
    printf("\nthis is working %s", word);
  }

  else if(*last_char == 'h')
  {
    *last_char = 'es';
    printf("\nPlural: %s", word);
  }

  else 
  {
    last_char = &word[(strlen(word))];
    *last_char = 's';
    printf("\nPlural: %s", word);
  }

   
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at what you said yourself:

> I get a warning when I try to set the last character equal to the plural ending.

You've got a memory slot for one character at that position and you're trying to squeeze many at that one slot. Isn't going to work.

`"ies";` is not a single character, it is a string - an array of characters that decays to a pointer to the first character. A single `char` is of integer type; you cannot convert a pointer to character (well you can, but it does not make sense).

In this case the simple solution would be to *`strcpy`* the ending to the subarray starting from `last_character`, i.e.:

```
strcpy(last_char, "ies");
```

As for

```
last_char = &word[(strlen(word))];
*last_char = 's';
```

that is not correct because the string would not be null-terminated!

remember that `last_char` was already pointing to the last character, and the null terminator after that is at address `last_char + 1`; you can replace these *two* lines with

```
strcpy(last_char + 1, "s");
```

Comment: Actually, `&word[strlen(word)]` is the address of the null-terminating character, since the first character of `word` is at offset `0`. Note that in the question, last_char is correctly defined as `&word[(strlen(word)-1)]`, even though it could be argued that OP should check that the input was not the empty string and initialize `word`  to `{0}`, but that's a bit nitpicking.

Comment: @Virgile actually nothing you did say contradicts anything I said in my answer, nor does my answer need any changes.

Comment: Well, your answer specifically says `last_char = &word[(strlen(word))]` and `strcpy(last_char + 1, "s");`, which would result in copying `s` after the null character.

Comment: @Virgile ok clarified.